How to detect if running on BrowserStack or local appium server in wdio
I have a wdio + cucumber framework + typescript + appium tests that run against a native app.
In the beforeScenario hook, I want to detect if I am running on browserstack or my local machine.
How can I do that?.
From what I see, I do not have access to the browser object and the driver object does not have access to config (so I could see if the browserstack service is listed).

So far my best way of doing this is to have different config files, one for invoking on local and another for browserstack.
These in turn call different hooks (local v browserstack) and in there I can know that I am on browserstack or not.

You can check if any session is created on BrowserStack
Also, please verify the integration steps per the below document:
https://www.browserstack.com/docs/app-automate/appium/getting-started/c-sharp/integrate-your-tests
There is a sample with WDIO+Cucumber+appium as well that you can refer:
https://github.com/BrowserStackCE/browserstack-webdriverio-appium-cucumber
